# How to represent a series reversion like this

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Consider the sequence: $$\sum_{k=0}^{0}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\sum_{k=0}^{1}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\cdots\;,\;\sum_{k=0}^{4}\alpha^{k}$$
This can be represented as:
$$
x_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha^{k}\quad \text{if $0\leq n\leq 4$}
$$
My question is for a sequence :
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{6}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\cdots\;,\;\sum_{k=5}^{6}\alpha^{k}\;,\;\sum_{k=6}^{6}\alpha^{k}
$$
How should I represent using sum notation the same way I did for the previous one? It seems this requires a double summation but I actually am just assuming. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write
$$x_n=\sum_{k=2+n}^6\alpha^k;$$
then $x_0$ will be the first sum you indicated, and $x_4$ will be the last sum, consisting only of $\alpha^6$. In general, modifying the indices of a summation is a very useful tool.